Expo SQLite does not believe 'transaction' to exist on type 'SQLiteDatabase'
I have been running into this issue for weeks. I have installed expo-sqlite into my React Native app, but can not use it without constantly running into blockers. Currently it believes that I cannot use either of these methods despite declaring on line 1 import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
db.transaction as Property 'transaction' does not exist on type 'SQLiteDatabase' 
db = SQLite.openDatabase("tasks.db") as Property 'openDatabase' does not exist on type ...node_modules/expo-sqlite/build/index")'. Did you mean 'openDatabaseSync'?
I think I can get around the issue of the .openDatabase by using a constructor as below, but it still prevents me from calling db.transaction:
db;
  constructor(db: SQLite.SQLiteDatabase) {
    this.db = db;
  }

I am running "expo": "^51.0.0" and "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.3"
I have tried using both newer and older versions of expo-sqlite in my project, but no luck.

Yes, a few weeks ago expo sqlite completely changed. To use the older version just import:
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite/legacy';
Legacy API docs
New API docs

Thank you! I missed that import from the docs. This saved me hours of rewriting the client with a new API.

I think you have to check the new documentation for expo-sqlite, they change all the method and structure: docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite
As the error says you have to use openDatabaseSync and for the transactions withTransactionAsync
